# How do you combine variables with strings in the disp method?

Tags: matlab, disp

I want to print out some text and then a variable but I can't work out how to do it.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
disp('Temperature is:');
disp(UU(90));
disp('After: ');
disp(timeInMinutes);
disp('minutes');
```

but I'd like to have it all in a single `disp`.

I've tried using %f where the variables should be and then putting a comma and the variable name at the end as well as: `disp('text ' + variable + 'more text');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate your desired output into a single string inside the `disp` function using the square brackets `[ ]`. You will also need to convert your numbers to strings using the `num2str` function.

Try this:

`disp(['Temperature is:' num2str(UU(90)) 'After: ' num2str(timeInMinutes) ' minutes']);`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function:

```
function superdisp(varargin)
    s= '';  
    for i=1:length(varargin)
        if isnumeric(varargin{i})
            s= [s num2str(varargin{i})];
        elseif ischar(varargin{i})
            s= [s varargin{i}];
        else
            error('Wrong argument!');
        end
    end
    disp(s);    % output the final string
end
```

Usage example:

```
superdisp('pi= ',pi,' e=',exp(1))
```

Or you can use `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(1,'pi=%f e=%f\n',pi,exp(1))
```